# How to rename an existing shared preferences file in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android. I have created SharedPreferences to store a playlist name and song names in the playlist. Now I have to rename the playlist.

And another is: How do I delete the SharedPreferences file (i.e `PlaylistName.xml`), when I delete the playlist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last, I am able to rename the sharedpreference file.

For reference, in my context the code is:

```
String fileName=etlistName.getText().toString();
File f=new File("/data/data/eywa.musicplayer/shared_prefs/"+PlayListName+".xml");
f.renameTo(new File("/data/data/eywa.musicplayer/shared_prefs/"+fileName+".xml"));

SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("list_of_playlist",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
editor.remove(PlayListName);
editor.putString(fileName, fileName);
editor.commit();
PlayListName=fileName;
```

And for deleting `playlistName.xml`:

```
for (int i=0; i<selectedItems.size();i++)
{//remove the songs names from the playlist
    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences(selectedItems.get(i),Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed=sp.edit();
    ed.clear();
    ed.commit();
    //remove the play list name from the list_of_playlist
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mainPref.edit();
    editor.remove(selectedItems.get(i));
    //delete .xml file
    File f=new File("/data/data/eywa.musicplayer/shared_prefs/"+selectedItems.get(i)+".xml");
    if(f.delete())
        System.out.println("file deleted")
    editor.commit();
}
selectedItems.clear();
```

Comment: oops! code is disturbed!
Please, try to understand. I am new to the site and android also

Thanks Vladimir Ivanov for suggestions.

Comment: you might want to up-vote his answer, then, if it helped. I've also submitted an edit for your answer to help clean up the formatting.

Answer (score 6):

The file access from "/data/data/..." is not reliable since I think it is not the same path for all the phones (Samsung devices namely are different AFAIK).

I prefer the following method which basically 'replicates' the old shared prefs and then clears it. This method does not remove the old shared prefs file itself but more relibale IMHO.

```
SharedPreferences settingsOld = context.getSharedPreferences(nameOld, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences settingsNew = context.getSharedPreferences(nameNew, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editorNew = settingsNew.edit();
Map<String, ?> all = settingsOld.getAll();
for (Entry<String, ?> x : all.entrySet()) {

    if      (x.getValue().getClass().equals(Boolean.class)) editorNew.putBoolean(x.getKey(), (Boolean)x.getValue());
    else if (x.getValue().getClass().equals(Float.class))   editorNew.putFloat(x.getKey(),   (Float)x.getValue());
    else if (x.getValue().getClass().equals(Integer.class)) editorNew.putInt(x.getKey(),     (Integer)x.getValue());
    else if (x.getValue().getClass().equals(Long.class))    editorNew.putLong(x.getKey(),    (Long)x.getValue());
    else if (x.getValue().getClass().equals(String.class))  editorNew.putString(x.getKey(),  (String)x.getValue());

}
editorNew.commit();
SharedPreferences.Editor editorOld = settingsOld.edit();
editorOld.clear();
editorOld.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen not the best storage for playlists. Database much more suits your needs. 
Although, you can still delete the sp file using basic java io.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Ok, I will use database. For deleting sp file, I used 'deleteFile(fileName);' It does not delete the file.