# how to modify sharedpreference name .I want to have specific name for preferences file

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Default the name of the preferences file saved on the device is always be _preferences. I want to modify it to "mypreference" on to the device how can I i do that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharedPreferences are stored in an xml file in the app data folder, i.e.

> /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml

or the default preferences at:

> /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml

SharedPreferences added during runtime are not stored in the Eclipse project.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146106/where-are-shared-preferences-stored).

For the custom name you'll want, take a look at this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788109/how-to-rename-an-existing-shared-preferences-file-in-android). For example:

```
String fileName="mypreference";
File f=new File("/data/data/eywa.musicplayer/shared_prefs/"+whatever+".xml");
f.renameTo(new File("/data/data/eywa.musicplayer/shared_prefs/"+fileName+".xml"));

SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("list_of_playlist",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
editor.remove(PlayListName);
editor.putString(fileName, fileName);
editor.commit();
PlayListName=fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a new preference file ([`getSharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) with the name "mypreference", and copy everything from "_preferences" to it.